# how to print project_name using project_id in Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

in My laravel app I have tasks table as below,

```
id      task_name      project_id
    1         aaa               1
    2         hjhkj             2
    3         jhghg             1
```

project table as below,

```
id     name   
1       abc
2       xyz
```

task model relationship with project model is

```
 public function project()
     {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
     }
```

I am printing  some data using task table in show.blade.php

```
{{$tasks->project_id}}

{{$tasks->task_name}}
```

actually now I need print project name here also, how can do this?

Comment: try this. {{$tasks->project->project_id}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
{{ $tasks->project->name }}
```